# How to print all fibonacci numbers before the n-th fibonacci number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fibonacci

I want to print all Fibonacci numbers to the one that has index n, but my code prints only the n-th Fibonacci number. please tell me what is that I'm doing wrong and how should it be done?

```
n = int(input('Enter a number: '))
def fibonacci(n): 
    if n < 0: 
        print("Error(enter a positive integer)") 
    elif n == 1: 
        return 0
    elif n == 2: 
        return 1
    else: 
        for i in range(n):
            return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

print(fibonacci(n))
```

Comment: Your `for` loop is in the wrong place. One solution here is to put the `print()` statement in a `for` loop. This is a terribly innefficient way to do it, but it will get the result you want.

Comment: Instead of using the dreaded doubly-recursive Fibonacci definition, which is horribly inefficient besides not being suited to printing them in ascending order, just start at the beginning and calculate them in the upwards direction.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        for i in range(n):
            return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
```

This for loop is meaningless since you `return` on the first iteration. You should just get rid of the for loop here entirely.

It is also not the part that you want to repeat. Instead, you want to repeat the `print()` statement:

```
for i in range(n):
    print(fibonacci(i)) # You want the i-th fibonacci number
```

This will get you the result you want, but it is a very inefficient way to do so. For large values of `n`, you will calculate the i-th fibonacci number an exponential number of times.

Answer (score 0):

If you are clever and your `n` is larger than 1, you might like to use `reduce` in more sophisticated way:

```
from functools import reduce
def fibonacci(n):
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x+[x[-1]+x[-2]], [[0,1]]+[[0]]*(n-2))
```

This is how it works for `n=5`:

```
[[0,1], [0], [0], [0]] -> 
[[0,1,1], [0], [0]] -> 
[[0,1,1,2], [0]] -> 
[[0,1,1,2,3]] -> 
stops here and returns [0,1,1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?:

```
def fib(l,ix):  
  a = [l[0], l[1]]
  for i in range(ix):
    b = a[i+1]+a[i]
    a.append(b)
  return str(a)[1:-1]
```

The first argument is for the first two numbers of your fibonacci (i.e, [0,1]). The second argument is to what number you want the fibonacci numbers to (i.e, 50).
This gives you something like `print(fib([0,1],50))` .